# Convert array of Ruby hashes to JSON (pretty) not using stdlib?

Tags: ruby, json

As per the question, just wondering how to do this without the use of the Ruby stdlib 'JSON' module (and thus the JSON.pretty_generate method).

So I have an array of hashes that looks like:

```
[{"h1"=>"a", "h2"=>"b", "h3"=>"c"}, {"h1"=>"d", "h2"=>"e", "h3"=>"f"}]
```

and I'd like to convert it so that it looks like the following:

```
[
  {
    "h1": "a",
    "h2": "b",
    "h3": "c",
  },
  {
    "h1": "d",
    "h2": "e",
    "h3": "f",
  }
]
```

I can get the hash-rockets replaced with colon spaces using a simple gsub (array_of_hashes.to_s.gsub!(/=>/, ": ")), but not sure about how to generate it so that it looks like the above example. I had originally thought of doing this use a here-doc approach, but not sure this is the best way, plus i havn't managed to get it working yet either. I'm new to Ruby so apologies if this is obvious! :-)

```
def to_json_pretty
        json_pretty = <<-EOM
[
  {
    "#{array_of_hashes.each { |hash| puts hash } }"
  },
]
EOM
        json_pretty
      end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, working with JSON well without using a library is going to take more than just a few lines of code. That being said, the best way of JSON-ifying things is generally to do it recursively, for example:

```
def pretty_json(obj)
  case obj
  when Array
    contents = obj.map {|x| pretty_json(x).gsub(/^/, "  ") }.join(",\n")
    "[\n#{contents}\n]"
  when Hash
    contents = obj.map {|k, v| "#{pretty_json(k.to_s)}: #{pretty_json(v)}".gsub(/^/, "  ") }.join(",\n")
    "{\n#{contents}\n}"
  else
    obj.inspect
  end
end
```

Comment: @Phrogz it's unclear what you're trying to say. mind pointing me at a better version?

Answer (score 0):

This should work well if you input is exactly in the format you presented and not nested:

```
a =  [{"h1"=>"a", "h2"=>"b", "h3"=>"c"}, {"h1"=>"d", "h2"=>"e", "h3"=>"f"}]
hstart = 0
astart = 0
a.each do |b|
  puts "[" if astart == 0
  astart+=1
  b.each do |key, value|
    puts " {" if hstart == 0 
    hstart += 1
    puts "   " + key.to_s + ' : ' + value
    if hstart % 2 == 0 
      if hstart ==  a.collect(&:size).reduce(:+)
        puts " }"  
      else
        puts " },\n {"
      end
    end
  end
  puts "]" if astart == a.size
end
```

Output:

```
[
 {
   h1 : a
   h2 : b
 },
 {
   h3 : c
   h1 : d
 },
 {
   h2 : e
   h3 : f
 }
]
```

Comment: Ya, this works for flat JSON responses but as you stated not for nested.  This can be solved with recursion.

Comment: yeah you can go ahead with that. I presumed your basic example and came up with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at my [NeatJSON](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON) gem for how I did it. Specifically, look at [`neatjson.rb`](https://github.com/Phrogz/NeatJSON/blob/master/lib/neatjson.rb), which uses a recursive solution (via a proc).

My code has a lot of variation based on what formatting options you supply, so it obviously does not have to be as complex as this. But the general pattern is to test the type of object supplied to your method/proc, serialize it if it's simple, or (if it's an Array or Hash) re-call the method/proc for each value inside.

Here's a far-simplified version (no indentation, no line wrapping, hard-coded spacing):

```ruby
def simple_json(object)
  js = ->(o) do
    case o
      when String               then o.inspect
      when Symbol               then o.to_s.inspect
      when Numeric              then o.to_s
      when TrueClass,FalseClass then o.to_s
      when NilClass             then "null"
      when Array                then "[ #{o.map{ |v| js[v] }.join ', '} ]"
      when Hash                 then "{ #{o.map{ |k,v| [js[k],js[v]].join ":"}.join ', '} }"
      else
        raise "I don't know how to deal with #{o.inspect}"
    end
  end
  js[object]
end


puts simple_json({a:1,b:[2,3,4],c:3})
#=> { "a":1, "b":[ 2, 3, 4 ], "c":3 }
```